# Iterate through database with PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need query 200+ tables in database.
By using spark.sql = f"" select ... " statement i get col(0) (because result of the query give me specific information about column that i've retrive) and result of calculation for particulare table, like this:

| col(0) |
| --- |
| 1 |

My goal is to have 1 csv file, with name of table and the result of calculation:

| Table name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| accounting | 3 |
| sales | 1 |

So far my main part of my code:

```
list_tables = ['accounting', 'sales',...]

for table in list_tables:
  df = spark.sql(
     f""" select distinct errors as counts from {database}.{table} where errors is not null""")

  df.repartition(1).write.mode("append").option("header","true").csv(f"s3:.......)
  rename_part_file(dir,output,newdir)
```

I'm kinda new to PySpark and all structures included.
Soo far i'm confused because i heard iteration dataframe isn't best idea.

By using following code i get only 1 csv with last recent record, not all processed tables from my list_tables.
Im stuck, don't know if there is possibility to pack all of it into 1 dataframe, or i should union dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Im stuck, don't know if there is possibility to pack all of it into 1 dataframe, or i should union dataframe?

Both of the options you mentioned lead to the same thing - you have to iterate over a list of tables (you can't read multiple tables at once), read each of it, execute a SQL statement and save the results into DataFrame, then union all of the DataFrames and save as a single CSV file. The sample code could look something like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from functools import reduce

tables = ["tableA", "tableB", "tableC"]
dfs = []
for table in tables:
    dfs.append(spark.read.table(table).sql("my sql statement").withColumn("TableName", lit(table))) # Append the DF with SQL query results

df = reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.union(df2), dfs) # Union all DFs
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").csv("my_csv.csv") # Combine and write as single file
```

**Note:** the `union` operation takes into account only the position of the column, and not its name. I assume for your case that is the desired behaviour, as your are only extracting a single statistic.

Comment: That 2 lines was something that i was looking for! 
Idk why but i had to use "import pyspark.sql import DataFrame df = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs), otherwise i got incorrect syntax error sparksql. Dzięki!